# Algorithm to find minimum in array of point

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have a vector of values with the minimum, but which is non-decreasing after it and non-increasing before. Here is the example:

```
std::vector<int> arr = {90, 80, 70, 60, 55, 62, 71, 89, 104}
```

In the example I want to find 55.
I want to be able to find its minimum efficiently. O(n) complexity is not enough. Supposedely, it is possible to some sort of modify binary search, but I would like to know whether there are existing solutions.

Comment: Well it is. It is non-increasing before and non-deceasing after this element

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can use binary search or Fibonacci search.  However, for small arrays, anything more complex than a linear search will not be negligible.

Comment: I do, I explicitly say "which is non-decreasing after it and non-increasing before"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part.

Comment: Nothing is built in, but you're right about modified binary search being sufficient in the general case.

Comment: @fiendfire28: Unfortunately "non-decreasing after it and non-increasing before" (guaranteeing no local minima) is not as strong a condition as convexity, and not strong enough to make binary search work.  Consider the following input which has no local minima but is not convex: `3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3`.   Comparing the middle element to either of its neighbors tells you nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve O(lg n) complexity as follows:

```
int findTurningPoint(const vector<int>& v, int begin, int end) {
    int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    if (v[mid - 1] > v[mid] && v[mid + 1] > v[mid]) {
        return mid;
    } else if (v[mid - 1] > v[mid]) {
        return findTurningPoint(v, mid + 1, end);
    } else if (v[mid - 1] < v[mid]) {
        return findTurningPoint(v, begin, mid - 1);
    }
}

vector<int> arr = {90, 80, 70, 60, 55, 62, 71, 89, 104};
cout << findTurningPoint(arr, 0, arr.size() - 1); // 4
```

**Method explained:**

Select the element in the middle of the vector. Check whether it forms a minima by comparing it with its neighbours. If not, find whether this element and its neighbours form an increasing sequence. If they do, repeat the above process for all elements to the left of the middle element. Otherwise, repeat the process for all elements to the right of the middle element.

Comment: If you give up the early exit in the case of getting lucky and landing right on the minimum, you can do each step with only two comparisons (`begin < end` and `v[mid] < v[mid+1]`).  Your current implementation can potentially read off both ends of the array, that's a problem too.

Comment: Also this `mid = (begin - end) / 2;` is just completely wrong (and always negative, ouch!).  You probably meant `mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;`

Comment: "*If you give up the early exit in the case of getting lucky and landing right on the minimum, you can do each step with only two comparisons (begin < end and v[mid] < v[mid+1])*" I don't get this. If the "lucky case" is eliminated then the recursion never stops.

Comment: That's the need to test `begin < end`... once your search space is down to a single element the recursion ends.  Just like in binary search.  Your current code doesn't handle that case correctly either, it happily lets begin and end cross each other.

Comment: "*Also this mid = (begin - end) / 2*" Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Besides that, `v[mid] < v[mid] + 1` alone won't work, because when I land on the desired element this condition will be true, so I also have to compare `v[mid]` with the previous element.

Comment: That isn't an exit condition, it is enough to decide which half of the search space to discard (based on "non-decreasing after and non-increasing before").  (And it should be `v[mid] < v[mid+1]` not `v[mid] + 1`)

Comment: You are assuming that the search always halts on `begin >= end` which is only true in the worst case.

Comment: My suggestion was that it may be better to let the search run until `begin>=end` (more iterations) if the cost of each iteration/recursion can be substantially reduced.  Right now you have as many as 6 comparisons per iteration/recursion, and you still aren't handling the base case (`begin==end` can't be ignored, because it can be true from the very first call) so that makes at least 7.  Reducing that to 2 or 3 likely is a net win even though the average iteration/recursion count increases when there is no early exit.

Comment: @WaisKamal For future reference, early exit in a binary search only saves one pass through the loop, on average. For example, imagine a binary search on an array of 127 elements. Only 1 of 127 elements can be found on the first attempt. 2 of 127 will be found on the second attempt. 4 in 3 attempts, 8 in 4 attempts, 16 in 5, 32 in 6, 64 in 7.  The average number of attempts is just over 6. So early exit, on average, saves one pass through the loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually I understood part of your suggestion and I will edit accordingly. Feel free to edit and reflect the rest of your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is missing the final `else` case and simply falls off the end of a value-returning function in that case, which is undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: Do you mean the case where `v[mid]` and `v[mid - 1]` are equal?